# When I use the WHERE clause my basic entity values are NULL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I want to refac a native SQL query with the doctrine querybuilder.
In this case I get the following error:
The query executes and returns a result (with and without joins).
But when I add a simple `WHERE` the basic entity values are `NULL`.

Tested
- QueryBuilder (complex: as default I need six joins)
- QueryBuilder (simple: no join)
- HQL
- different `getResult()` and `execute()` calls

#### Versions:

PHP 7.0 (no updates possible ...)

```sh
 ./composer.phar info | grep doctrine
doctrine/annotations                 v1.4.0   Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.6.2   Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                 v1.4.0   Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.7.3   Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.13  Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.10.3   Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       1.3.5    Symfony Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/inflector                   v1.2.0   Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                1.0.5    A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their cons...
doctrine/lexer                       1.0.2    PHP Doctrine Lexer parser library that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Pars...
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.14  Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
```

#### Some code

**The basic values are filled (like `id` and `title`).**

```php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('artikel')
           ;
return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

**The basic values are `null` except the `id`.**

```php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('artikel')
           ->andWhere('artikel.id = :ids')
           ->setParameter('ids', '1010729320')
           ;
return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Why are the basic value `null` when I use the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I guess you would have already tried this but is `1010729320` actually an ID? Have you double checked that, if you're using fixture data I would say to double check :)

Comment: @SwitchCase Yes I checked it some times but the id is the trick!

It's a string param and the id is an integer of course. 
I delete the `'`s and it runs like expected. :D 

Why it happen: 
In my code it's the 2nd query after one query, which delifers the ids to do the `joins`. It's interessting for me, that the other entity delivers a string instead of the used integer. 

Thank you and I will add an answer with the solution.

Comment: Rubber ducking helped you out there then mate! Well done haha

Comment: hehe, yepp! Sometimes it needs a kind of commitment like Stackoverflow. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy. ;)

#### Problem was

The datatype of the `id` is an `integer` and the given param has type `string`.
So it differs and php does no auto-cast something.

#### Solution

Remove the `'` before and after the id.

#### The correct code

Note: spot the missing `'`

```php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('artikel')
           ->andWhere('artikel.id = :ids')
           ->setParameter('ids', 1010729320)
           ;
return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

For me the problem occures before, but this is an other story (I write some cents in the comment above).

Thank you all